# Puppeteer evaluate function wont update html form value but developer console will

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, puppeteer

I am trying input data into a form element on a web page using the .evaluate function but keep getting the error:

"Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null at **puppeteer_evaluation_script**:2:142"

I know that I am most likely not doing something right but what is confusing me is that I can then take the same code in the evaluate function, run it in the developer console, and it will update the input value.
Here is the code in the evaluate

```
await page.evaluate(async() => {
  iframe1 = document.querySelector("#mainarea");
  doc = mainareaFrame.contentDocument;
  iframe2 = doc.querySelector("#getFrame");
  doc1 = getFrame.contentDocument;
  doc1.querySelector("#RS_sso_order__3").value = "HI";
});
```

I should also mention that the form I am trying to fill is nested inside 2 iframes which I believe is giving me most of my issues.

Why is the same exact code working in the console but not in the evaluate?
Additionally, is there a better way to access the form than what I am currently doing.

Comment: Maybe `RS_sso_order__3` is not there yet?

Comment: I am already doing  `await page.waitForSelector("mainarea")` and the form is visible once that iframe has loaded so I don't think that is the issue.